# sax parser throws FileNotFound after exchanging characters in file name

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am trying to parse a file with a ^ in the file name.  The problem is that after passing it to the parser, it changes the ^ to a %5, resulting in the file not being found.  Is there a sax feature or property I can set so the ^ is not replaced?

Thanks

Comment: possible to post little bit of code, of reading file name using SAX Parser

Comment: And you need to tell us which SAX parser you are using. There are many, and it's quite likely that they differ in this kind of area.